# c# древо папок visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf

Народ подскажите есть задача, есть папка где есть подпапки и в них ссылки, мне нужно сделать wpf приложение разделенное визуально на две части, в одной части будут папки а в другой ссылки хранящиеся в этих папках которое можно будет кликом открыть, подскажите как можно реализовать подобное с помощью каких элементов хотя бы на толкните на мысль

Comment: ListBox.‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏

Comment: Реализация первой части приложения: [youtube tutorial #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OwyNiLPDNw) и [youtube tutorial #3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2ZvZwDZmJU). 2-ую часть будет сделать проще.

Comment: Вы сами что-нибудь сделали? Пытались? Если нет, то вот вам необходимые компоненты [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx), [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) а также вам понадобятся шаблоны [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) для `TreeView` и возможно [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) для `ListView`.

Comment: По поводу папок, если Вы имели ввиду папки на диске, то обратитесь к `namespace System.IO`, а именно [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) и [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваши ингредиенты:

- [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) - для отображения древовидной структуры папок.
- [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) - что бы отобразить файлы в папке; или любой другой элемент управления списками.
- [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) - для получения списка папок и файлов.
- [Prism](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/), [MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) или любой другой MVVM-фреймворк.

Затем:

- Создаете WPF-проект.
- Создаете `Model`'и, которые будут представлять ваши файлы, папки и т.п.
- Создаете `VewModel`, которая будет содержать вашу логику, например, по отображению файлов в папке. Во `VewModel` пригодится:

  - коллекция, которая будет содержать древовидный список ваших папок.
  - свойство, которое будет представлять выбранную в дереве папку.
  - коллекция, которая будет содержать список файлов для выбранной папки.
- Далее осуществляете привязку свойств из `ViewModel` с `View`.
- Затем рекурсивно (*рекурсию нужно реализовать самому*) получаете список папок, метод [Directory.GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx)  может вам в этом помочь, преобразуете их в ваш тип модели, представляющих папку и добавляете в коллекцию содержащую список ваших папок.
- При выборе в элементе `TreeView` конкретной папки, получаете список файлов, содержащихся в ней, используя, например, [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx). После чего преобразуете их в тип модели, представляющих ваш файл и добавляете в коллекцию, отображающую список файлов для выбранной папки.

Comment: не забываем модели наследовать от [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А скажите если делать не через treeview а через list box без иерархии это реально ?

Comment: @bandy07 используя `ListBox` вы не сможете показать иерархию (вложенность), что концептуально выглядит не очень красиво. Но если отбросить красоту, можно сделать следующее: получаем иерархический список всех папок, затем преобразуем его к плоскому виду и уже этот плоский список отображаем в `ListBox`.

Comment: а какими методами это можно реализовать я в c# новичок...

Comment: Список  папок можно получить используя `Directory.GetDirectories()`, но рекурсию придется написать самому, она нужна для того, что бы была возможность получить список папок с учетом вложенности, а данный метод возвращает только список папок первого уровня.